# How to efficiently find pairs of numbers where the square of one equals the cube of the other?

Tags: python, time-complexity, nested-loops

I need to find the pairs `(i,j)` and number of pairs for a number `N` such that the below conditions are satisfied:
1 <= i <= j <= N and also i * i * i = j * j.

For example, for `N = 50`, number of pairs is 3 i.e., `(1,1)`, `(4,8)`, `(9,27)`.

I tried the below function code but it takes too much time for a large number like `N = 10000` or more:

```
def compute_pairs(N):
    pair = []
   
    for i in range (1, N):
        for j in range (i, N):
            print( 'j =', j)
            if i*i*i == j*j:
                new_pair = (i,j)
                pair.append(new_pair)
    print(pair)
    return len(pair)
```

Comment: Do you have to try every possible value of `i` in order to know whether `i*i*i` is equal to `j*j`? After you calculate `j*j`, perhaps you can think of a simple mathematical rule that tells you the value of `i`? If you have that value, can you think of an easy way to check whether it's an integer?

Comment: (You will have to do a bit more work because of floating point imprecision, but you can probably see a much faster approach this way.)

Comment: `i**3 == j**2` :  there's no need to run a loop on `j`, a single test (is sqrt(i**3) an integer?) is enough. The time complexity should only be smaller than O(N).

Comment: Alternately: try looking at the first few results that you get for a small N. Notice a pattern? Can you prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `k` be the square root of some integer `i` satisfying `i*i*i == j*j`, where `j` is also an integer. Since `k` is the square root of an integer, `k*k` is integer. From the equation, we can solve that `j` is equal to `k*k*k`, so that is also an integer.

Since `k*k*k` is an integer and `k*k` is an integer, it follows by dividing these two that `k` is rational. But `k` is the square root of an integer, so it must be either an integer or irrational. Since it is rational, it must be an integer.

Since `k` is an integer, all the solutions are simply `(k*k, k*k*k)` for integer `k`. Since we will iterate over `k>=1`, we know that `k*k <= k*k*k`, i.e. `i <= j`, so we don't have to worry about that. We just have to stop iterating when `k*k*k` reaches `N`.

```
from itertools import count # unbounded range; we will `break` when appropriate
def compute_pairs(N):
    result = []
    for k in count(1):
        i, j = k*k, k*k*k
        if j >= N:
            break
        result.append((i, j))
    return result
```

This runs almost instantaneously even for `N` of 100000, no C-level optimization needed.

Comment: Might even be appropriate to yield the (i, j) pairs out. A list can be built from the generator if needed.

Comment: Side Note: Your code iterates from '0' to 'N', the post owner iterates from '1' to 'N-1'.

Comment: I iterate indefinitely, and break at the cube root of `N`. I agree that `(0, 0)` should not be counted as a solution; edited accordingly.

Comment: If you run your code for `N=1000` you get `[(1, 1), (4, 8), (9, 27), (16, 64), (25, 125), (36, 216), (49, 343), (64, 512), (81, 729), (100, 1000)]` while the post owner gets `[(1, 1), (4, 8), (9, 27), (16, 64), (25, 125), (36, 216), (49, 343), (64, 512), (81, 729)]` for his code. May decrease N by one. or make it `if j >= N`

Comment: `j >= N` is the semantically correct fix. Applied.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the problem. You need `i` cubed to be the same as `j` squared?

We know that pairs like `(0, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, `(4, 8)`, and `(9, 27)` satisfy this condition.

What do `0`, `1`, `4`, and `9` all have in common?

They're `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` squared.

What then do `0`, `1`, `8`, and `27` all have in common?

They're the *same* numbers cubed.

Once you realize the pattern, the answer can be calculated in extremely short time.

Comment: Very nice. So, the answer is really just: `[(pow(x,2),pow(x,3)) for x in range(1,int(N**(1/3))+1)]`? Definitely faster than the other answers.

Comment: @ouroboros1 that is functionally equivalent to my answer (except I do not take chances with floating-point for determining the bounds of the range). I also gave an actual mathematical proof for the pattern.

Comment: Sure, I was a little confused why you felt the need for `if j > N: break`, but the floating-point issue makes sense.